# jQuery - bind and execute a single handler?

Tags: jquery

I find myself often needing to bind an event handler, as well as immediately execute that handler in jQuery.  To date, I've been using this lazy faux-pattern to keep the code DRY:

```
$(...).bind('event', function() {
    ...
}).trigger('event');
```

Today I was bitten by this, due to the fact that other handlers had already been bound to `event`, and they were also executed when I triggered the event in this way, but caused a lot of problems, since they weren't supposed to have been executed at that time.

To resolve the problem, I've changed the pattern to this:

```
var handler = function() {
    ...
};

var element = $(...);

element.bind('event', handler);
handler.call(element);
```

This works the way I expect, but it's ugly as sin and quite verbose, so I'm considering encapsulating this pattern into a jQuery plugin:

```
$(...).bindAndExecute('event', function() { ... });
```

I could find no equivalent for this in `jQuery.bind()` options or any of the other methods, but I may have missed something.  Is there a more concise way of doing this that I haven't thought of?  I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery supports [namespacing your events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). This is a very useful technique and comes quite handy when you want unbind or trigger a specific group of events.

```
$(...).bind('event.myNamespace', function() {
    ...
}).trigger('event.myNamespace');
```

Using this technique is almost unavoidable (or at least sensible people won't avoid it) when you are developing bigger applications or jQuery plugins.

[Quick jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4hE/1/)

Comment: I don't understand this suggestion.  Could you explain?

Comment: I'm not using custom events, so I'm unsure how this applies to my situation.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, you can namespace "standard" events too.

Comment: Ohh!  Thanks for the link, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Can't believe I didn't know about it.  +1